# Bootstrap - table css issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

I got an issue with the table's style.

When I try to change the `<thead>`'s padding, it doesn't change.

And it happens with more style element.

That's my code:

http://pastebin.com/xHhHMZmP

And here is the result:
[image: Table's result]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to add the `!important` flag for your padding:

```
table th{
  padding: 50px !important;
  background-color: #ffb74d;
  color:#EEEEEE
}
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rL96X/)

Comment: Thanks! can you just explain me what is the !important does?

Comment: @iYonatan - The !important flag overwrites any other styling (including inline) that may have affect on the elements given css property. E.g. you have an element that has an inline style with color black and in your external css you have the color set to blue. Normally inline styling overwrites external styling. But the `!important` flag tips it over. As in `!important` says, the element MUST use this property with this value.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at your code, here is what I noticed. Your CSS is defining...

```
table th{
          padding: 50px;
         background-color: #ffb74d;
         color:#EEEEEE

     }
```

But on those `<th>` you've got classes and inline styles. Better to define all this in one place for consistency.

Try...

```
table > thead > th {
              padding: 50px;
             background-color: #ffb74d;
             color:#EEEEEE

                    }
```

Comment: Seems that there is padding there but the text is not vertically centered? Or did you just remove the orange background?

Comment: I didnt remove the background color